# How to render JSON data depending on input value

Tags: javascript, json

**Background:**

I am working on a mini project learning how to use AJAX via vanilla JavaScript with a JSON file. I am aware I can use Jquery but I am learning the long way and Jquery will be next.

**Goal:**

My goal is to be able to type in a city and once I click the button it will render the current weather for the city I typed in.

**Problem:**

I cannot figure out and am looking for guidance on how to essentially take the value and attach it to a key and render all the data I am seeking. My thought process is to bring in the input value and compare it to the name key and if they are a match render the results. I just can't wrap my head around how that could look in code so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**What I have:**

So far I am able to render what I want by hard-coding with the following file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Ajax3 - JSON(external api practice) File</title>
</head>
<body>
   <input id="city">
   <button id="button">Get Weather</button>
   <br><br>
   <h1>Weather</h1>
   <div id='weather'></div>
   <script>
           // Create an event listener
           document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', loadWeather);
           function loadWeather(){
               // console.log(city);
               let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               xhr.open('GET', 'weather.json', true);
               xhr.onload = function(){
                   let city = document.getElementById('city').value;
                   // let keys = Object.keys(weather);
                   if(this.status == 200){
                       let weatherTest = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                       let result = '';
                   //   weather.forEach((item, index) =>{
                       result += '<ul>'+
                           '<li>City: '+JSON.stringify(weatherTest[1].name )+ '</li>' +
                           '<li>Weather: '+JSON.stringify(weatherTest[1].weather[0].description )+ '</li>' +
                           '<li>Latitude: '+JSON.stringify(weatherTest[1].coord.lat )+ '</li>' +
                           '<li>Longitude: '+JSON.stringify(weatherTest[1].coord.lon )+ '</li>' +
                           '</ul>';
                           document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = result;
                   //   })
                   }
               }
               xhr.send();
           }
           //HTTP statuses
           // 200: 'Ok'
           // 403: 'Forbidden'
           // 404: 'Not Found'
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSON file data I am working with:

```
[{
   "coord":{
      "lon":-62.08,
      "lat":-31.43
   },
   "sys":{
      "message":0.3897,
      "country":"AR",
      "sunrise":1428575101,
      "sunset":1428616476
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":802,
         "main":"Clouds",
         "description":"scattered clouds",
         "icon":"03d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":303.364,
      "temp_min":303.364,
      "temp_max":303.364,
      "pressure":1015.65,
      "sea_level":1026.91,
      "grnd_level":1015.65,
      "humidity":42
   },
   "wind":{
      "speed":2.85,
      "deg":32.0037
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":44
   },
   "dt":1428614645,
   "id":3837675,
   "name":"San Francisco",
   "cod":200
 },
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":-87.65,
      "lat":41.85
   },
   "sys":{
      "message":0.014,
      "country":"US",
      "sunrise":1428578344,
      "sunset":1428625502
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":501,
         "main":"Rain",
         "description":"moderate rain",
         "icon":"10d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":286.264,
      "temp_min":286.264,
      "temp_max":286.264,
      "pressure":991.9,
      "sea_level":1013.82,
      "grnd_level":991.9,
      "humidity":76
   },
   "wind":{
      "speed":8.25,
      "deg":202.004
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":92
   },
   "rain":{
      "3h":4.61
   },
   "dt":1428615189,
   "id":4887398,
   "name":"Chicago",
   "cod":200
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Todd R said, you just have to find the array element you actually want before accessing the properties. You also don't need `JSON.stringify` as the values are already strings or numbers and can be put straight into the HTML. Wrapping them in a stringify call will result in quotes being added to the string values eg.

`<li>City: "San Francisco"</li>`

Example code:

```
xhr.onload = function(){
    const city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    if(this.status == 200){
        let cityWeathers;
        try {
            cityWeathers = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        } catch (e) {
            // JSON not valid, show error message
        }
        const cityWeather = Array.isArray(cityWeathers) && cityWeathers.find((obj)=>obj.name === city);
        if (cityWeather) {
            const result = `<ul><li>City: ${cityWeather.name}</li>` +
                `<li>Weather: ${cityWeather.weather[0].description}</li>` + 
                `<li>Latitude: ${cityWeather.coord.lat}</li>` +
                `<li>Longitude: ${cityWeather.coord.lon}</li></ul>`;

            document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Where your "forEach" comment starts, go through weatherTest to "find" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the element that matches "city". Then use the element you return from "find" to build "result".

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different demo, showing the use of `fetch()` as a new Vanilla Javascript way of doing Ajax:

I only get the data once (at load time and then scan the array for a pattern that matches the city. This is bound to the `keyup` event of the input field, making the button obsolete.

```js
var data, ct=document.querySelector('#city'), wt=document.querySelector('#weather');
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(function(r){r.json().then(function(da){data=da;
  document.querySelector('#all').innerHTML=data.map(function(v){return v.address.city}).join(', ');});
})

ct.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
 wt.innerHTML='';
 var i,n=data.length, rx=new RegExp(ct.value,'i');
 for (i=0;i<n;i++) if (rx.test(data[i].address.city)) {
   wt.innerHTML=data[i].address.city+': '+data[i].address.zipcode 
 }
});
```

```html
<input id="city"><br>
<div id="all"></div>
<h1>City and zip code</h1>
<div id='weather'></div>
```